# how can i read qr code with camera preview in flutter

Tags: flutter

her is my code which i was use for display camera but issue is what i do for scan qr code.
please help me.

```
  Widget camera() {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.myColor, width: 1.0)),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          child: new SizedBox(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.5,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
            child: new AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: CameraPreview(controller),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        new Container(
          height: 100.0,
          width: 100.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.myColor, width: 2.0)),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need to use a third party librairy.
You can fin some when using google with thos keywords : barcode scanner + flutter
Some examples :
[barcode_scan](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_scan) 
[qr_mobile_vision](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/qr_mobile_vision)

Answer (score 5):

This can be done by using flutter [barcode_scan](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/barcode_scan) dependency.

```
Future _openQRScanner() async {
try {
  // Below code will open camera preview and return result after qr scan 
  String _content = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
  setState(() => this._content = _content);
} on PlatformException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
    showSnackBar('Please grant camera permission!');
    setState(() {
      this._content = null;
    });
  } else {
    showSnackBar('Error: $e');
    setState(() {
      this._content = null;
    });
  }
} on FormatException {
  showSnackBar('User pressed "back" button before scanning');
  setState(() {
    this._content = null;
  });
} catch (e) {
  showSnackBar('Error: $e');
  setState(() {
    this._content = null;
  });
}
}
```

[image]

[image]

Please find the [repo](https://github.com/flutter-devs/flutter_qr_code_scanner).

If you want to take a look at Flutter you can find some good examples at our [companie’s Github](https://github.com/flutter-devs) page. Also, you can check our company's page [FlutterDevs](http://www.flutterdevs.com/).

Comment: Is there a way to do changes to scanner preview ?